# Centering text inside a canvas rectangle (button)

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

Is there a dynamic way to center the text based on the height, width, X, Y, or a rectangle and the text length?  I'm having a bear trying to manually figuring out the X/Y coordinates for a button text.

Ignoring that I'm using a method roundRect to make rounded edges, what is a good way to center the text?

```
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillStyle = "#abc";
roundRect(ctx, 10, 10, 100, 50, 10, true);
ctx.font="20px Georgia";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
var rectHeight = 50;
var rectWidth = 100;
var rectX = 10;
var rectY = 10;
ctx.fillText("Attack!",rectX+(rectWidth/2),rectY+(rectHeight/2));
```

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vu7dZ/1/

Comment: Perhaps you should use the [`textAlign`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_textalign.asp) property of `ctx`?

Comment: @Noble...Yep, that's right!

Comment: That seems to get part of the way there http://jsfiddle.net/vu7dZ/2/  Is there a textAlign for the vertical coordinates?

Comment: heyyyyy ctx.textBaseline="middle" get the vertical alignment! http://jsfiddle.net/vu7dZ/3/

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The answer lays mostly in `textAlign="center"` and `textBaseline="middle"`. These two properties align the text in the horizontal space and vertical space respectively.

```
ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillStyle = "#abc";
roundRect(ctx, 10, 10, 100, 50, 10, true);
ctx.font="20px Georgia";
ctx.textAlign="center"; 
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
var rectHeight = 50;
var rectWidth = 100;
var rectX = 10;
var rectY = 10;
ctx.fillText("Attack!",rectX+(rectWidth/2),rectY+(rectHeight/2));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vu7dZ/4/

Comment: What if the rectangle is horizontally centered in the canvas itself?

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for

Comment: In case anyone needs it, I've updated the fiddle to make the text fit the box by reducing the text size if it's too large to fit. http://jsfiddle.net/andyg2/Lb7x0p5e/3/

Comment: Or to make the rectangle larger to fit the text http://jsfiddle.net/andyg2/Lb7x0p5e/4/